# Spring batch - InputStream as parameter for ItemReader

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

Is there a way to add a parameter in spring batch as inputstream instead of the file path?

Comment: why do you want to use an itemstream instead of the path?

Comment: I am trying to use batch that makes use of Streaming InputStream

Comment: please add what you tried so far, e.g. xml/javaconfig for your job

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own custom reader and pass the InputStream with setResource.

```
yourReader.setResource(new InputStreamResource(inputStream));
```

Comment: how do you pass this inputstream from the Job Parameters?

Comment: As far as i know you cannot pass InputStream as a job parameter. The only way would be to inject the input stream to your custom reader bean.